# Вызов функции на ассеблере из си ?

Tags: c, ассемблер, masm32

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема в лабораторной работе, по ассемблеру.

Задача:
Есть арифметическое выражение, его нужно вычислить. Есть клиентский код на си, в котором вводятся 3 перменные, далее они передаются в процедуру на ассемблере, которая и производит вычисление, так же выражение необходимо вычислить в си-шном коде, для проверки.

Проблема: судя по отладчику, все вычисления происходят нормально, но вернуть резултат из асм модуля в си не получается. Препод говорил организовать обмен переменными таким образом: в си объявить глобальные переменные передать их в асм модуль при помощи директивы extern. Сразу показалось странным -- ведь это же получается локальная переменная которая при выходе из функции уничтожится? 
Пытался передавать 4 параметра процедере асм-модуля: 3 значения и указатель на переменную в которую нужно записать результат, но в итоге результат такой же как и с extern'ом.

Я в тупике.
Прошу помочь, заранее спасибо.
Компилятор: Visual Studio 2010
Ассемблер:  MASM

Исходник си модуля: [гитхаб](https://gist.github.com/cryptohedge/6743221#file-main-c)

Исходник асм модуля: [гитхаб](https://gist.github.com/cryptohedge/6743221#file-mod_as-asm)

Comment: > ведь это же получается локальная переменная которая при выходе из функции уничтожится?

Внезапно. Откуда такой вывод?

Comment: Из си-кода параметры передаете через стек (в скобочках), а в асм-коде обращаетесь к ним как к внешним глобальным переменным. Возвращать значение из функции можно через регистр eax, а в си-коде его получать примерно так: result = get_asm_unbyte(

Comment: А разве не так? Это же по идее тоже функция, но написана на ассемблере, а не на си. Следовательно переменные переданные в данную функцию локальные, при выходе из функции -- уничтожаются.

Comment: > Сразу показалось странным -- ведь это же получается локальная переменная которая при выходе из функции уничтожится?

Локальные переменные не могут быть внешними.

Comment: @chedge если есть функция `void foo(int a){int b;}` то a и b локальны по отношению к функции `foo`, всё что объявлено вне функций (вообще всех) будет глобально по отношению к `foo` 

    #include <...>
    
    int X;//глобальна для всех
    
    int main()
    {
        //...
    }

    void foo()
    {
        //...
    }

Comment: Скажите вашему преподу, что передача параметров через глобальные переменные устарела лет 50 назад, и что в нормальных проектах за такое немедленно увольняют с ужасной рекомендацией.

Выучите соглашения вашего компилятора о передаче параметров. Скорее всего параметры «простых» типов передаются через стек или через регистры, а возвращаемое значение передаётся через фиксированный регистр (например, `al`/`ax`/`eax` на интеловских процессорах).